# Read a YAML file in C#?

Tags: c#, yaml

I am trying to read a .yaml file into my C# application, and store the data in a custom class. I am attempting this using `YamlDotNet` from nuget.

The file is pasted below, and the code I have (from the YamlDotNet examples) is:

```
public void readMapFile(string filepath)
{
    // Setup the input
    var input = new StringReader(filepath);

    // Load the stream
    var yaml = new YamlStream();
    yaml.Load(input);

    // Examine the stream
    var mapping = (YamlMappingNode)yaml.Documents[0].RootNode;

    foreach (var entry in mapping.Children)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(((YamlScalarNode)entry.Key).Value);
    }

    // List all the items
    var items = (YamlSequenceNode)mapping.Children[new YamlScalarNode("aruco_bc_markers")];
}
```

This crashes, however, giving me the error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'YamlDotNet.RepresentationModel.YamlScalarNode' to type 'YamlDotNet.RepresentationModel.YamlMappingNode'.`

I am new to this kind of file reading and I am stuck.

Where am I going wrong?

```
%YAML:1.0
---
aruco_bc_dict: ARUCO
aruco_bc_nmarkers: 24
aruco_bc_mInfoType: 1
aruco_bc_markers:
   - { id:0, corners:[ [ -1.2928584814071655e+00, 8.1286805868148804e-01,
       -1.6458697617053986e-01 ], [ -1.1746160984039307e+00,
       8.1223398447036743e-01, -1.4413379132747650e-01 ], [
       -1.1754947900772095e+00, 6.9224494695663452e-01,
       -1.4277370274066925e-01 ], [ -1.2937371730804443e+00,
       6.9287902116775513e-01, -1.6322688758373260e-01 ] ] }
   - { id:1, corners:[ [ -7.9834830760955811e-01, 8.1106305122375488e-01,
       -9.9434338510036469e-02 ], [ -6.7920655012130737e-01,
       8.1078404188156128e-01, -8.5110619664192200e-02 ], [
       -6.7947661876678467e-01, 6.9078433513641357e-01,
       -8.5201270878314972e-02 ], [ -7.9861837625503540e-01,
       6.9106334447860718e-01, -9.9524989724159241e-02 ] ] }
   - { id:2, corners:[ [ -3.0384334921836853e-01, 8.1034839153289795e-01,
       -3.8991540670394897e-02 ], [ -1.8399941921234131e-01,
       8.1008774042129517e-01, -3.2878942787647247e-02 ], [
       -1.8429389595985413e-01, 6.9008994102478027e-01,
       -3.2222278416156769e-02 ], [ -3.0413782596588135e-01,
       6.9035059213638306e-01, -3.8334876298904419e-02 ] ] }
```

Comment: Psychic debugging prediction: `yaml.Documents[0].RootNode` is a `YamlScalarNode`. What's YAML?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. `yaml` is ` var yaml = new YamlStream();`, as above. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand. The variable `yaml` is lower case throughout.

Comment: If you google it, the author suggests a different approach that's marked `[Obsolete]` in the released library.

Comment: I'm not big expert but your YAML seems to be invalid, where did you get it?

Comment: It is a mapping file returned from a Fiducial marker library. Aruco, to be precise.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, thank you! i will look for another parser.

Comment: Well, as I said that was my first reaction. For all I know this may be the best. The question is just how to get it to sit up and bark.

Comment: A-ha! OP, `StringReader` just reads the string. You want `var input = new StreamReader(filepath);`, to read a file. So much for my first reaction! This gets me a syntax error with your YAML text, however.

Comment: Ok! me too. `Unhandled Exception: YamlDotNet.Core.SyntaxErrorException: (Line: 1, Col: 1, Idx: 0) - (Line: 1, Col: 6, Idx: 5): While scanning a directive, find unexpected non-alphabetical character.`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First problem is you are reading filename itself as yaml document, not file contents. Use `StreamReader` instead of `StringReader`:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(filepath)) {
    // Load the stream
    var yaml = new YamlStream();
    yaml.Load(reader);
    // the rest
}
```

Then, YAML 1.0 is VERY old, so it seems parser does not understand `%YAML: 1.0` directive (in later versions the ":" was removed from this directive). So remove it and "---" (not needed). Instead of removing you can change it to `%YAML 1.1` (no ":", version 1.1, 1.0 is rejected by parser).

Then, intendation is important. This version (note spaces after ":" in "id" and "corners") will be parsed with your code without issues:

```
%YAML 1.1
---
aruco_bc_dict: ARUCO
aruco_bc_nmarkers: 24
aruco_bc_mInfoType: 1
aruco_bc_markers:
   - { id: 0, corners: [ [ -1.2928584814071655e+00, 8.1286805868148804e-01,
       -1.6458697617053986e-01 ], [ -1.1746160984039307e+00,
       8.1223398447036743e-01, -1.4413379132747650e-01 ], [
       -1.1754947900772095e+00, 6.9224494695663452e-01,
       -1.4277370274066925e-01 ], [ -1.2937371730804443e+00,
       6.9287902116775513e-01, -1.6322688758373260e-01 ] ] }
   - { id: 1, corners: [ [ -7.9834830760955811e-01, 8.1106305122375488e-01,
       -9.9434338510036469e-02 ], [ -6.7920655012130737e-01,
       8.1078404188156128e-01, -8.5110619664192200e-02 ], [
       -6.7947661876678467e-01, 6.9078433513641357e-01,
       -8.5201270878314972e-02 ], [ -7.9861837625503540e-01,
       6.9106334447860718e-01, -9.9524989724159241e-02 ] ] }
   - { id: 2, corners: [ [ -3.0384334921836853e-01, 8.1034839153289795e-01,
       -3.8991540670394897e-02 ], [ -1.8399941921234131e-01,
       8.1008774042129517e-01, -3.2878942787647247e-02 ], [
       -1.8429389595985413e-01, 6.9008994102478027e-01,
       -3.2222278416156769e-02 ], [ -3.0413782596588135e-01,
       6.9035059213638306e-01, -3.8334876298904419e-02 ] ] }
```

Comment: Thank you. I have adjusted the file, and i still see this error: `Unhandled Exception: YamlDotNet.Core.SyntaxErrorException: (Line: 1, Col: 1, Idx: 0) - (Line: 1, Col: 6, Idx: 5): While scanning a directive, find unexpected non-alphabetical character.`

Comment: hmm actually, pasting the top lines from your sample has helped. But they looked the same...

Comment: @anti that means you did not really adjusted it - it complains about %YAML: 1.0 directive most likely. Just copy-paste my sample as is (because all changes are important).

Comment: The files are created by a third party application that i will need to edit. So just to be clear: Sapces after `id:`, spaces after `corners:`, and `%YAML 1.1`. is that all? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, that's all I changed. I also pasted your yaml here: http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ and it didn't like lack of spaces and YAML directive also, so it's not just this parser.